# Something is wrong with the implementation of the ThueMorse function

Tags: integer-sequence, binary

While trying to answer [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220855/are-any-values-of-this-sum-involving-the-thue-morse-sequence-known), I believe I found several bugs in Mathematica and Alpha relating to the Thue-Morse sequence.

As a quick reminder, the $n^{\rm th}$ element of the Thue-Morse sequence (denoted here by $t_n$) is $1$ if the sum of its binary digits contains an odd number of $1$s, $0$ otherwise.

In essence, I typed the function
$$
\zeta_{TM}(s) = \sum_{n\geq0} \frac{t_{n}}{(n+1)^s}
$$
[in Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(+ThueMorse%5Bn%5D%2F(n%2B1)%5Es+),+n%3D0+to+infinity), which surprisingly gave
$$
\zeta_{TM}(s) = 2^{-s}\zeta(s),
$$
where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann Zeta function. This is obviously wrong as the LHS does not converge to the RHS for any $s>1$. Upon further inspection, it appears that Alpha translated `ThueMorse[n]` to `Mod[Plus @@ IntegerDigits[n, 2], 2]`, which is perfectly fine as this is the definition of the Thue-Morse sequence.

Turning to Mathematica to resolve this conundrum, I found that it too makes the same mistake. Inputting

```
Sum[Mod[Plus @@ IntegerDigits[n, 2], 2]/(n + 1)^s, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

returns

```
2^-s Zeta[s]
```

which again is obviously wrong. Taking the example of $s=3$ and computing the partial sums up to a positive integer $m$ and dividing them with $2^{-s}\zeta(s)$ clearly shows that they diverge:

```
s = 3
Table[N[Sum[Mod[Plus @@ IntegerDigits[n, 2], 2]/(n + 1)^s, {n, 0, 10^m}]]/(2^{-s}*Zeta[s]), {m, 1, 5}]
```

gives

```
{{1.15377}, {1.16799}, {1.16814}, {1.16814}, {1.16814}}
```

which most certainly does not converge to $1$.

So what is going on here? Is this truly a bug in Alpha and Mathematica, or am I missing something very obvious?

---

For info, I am using Mathematica 11.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. See the tag description for why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the following:

```
Mod[Plus @@ IntegerDigits[n, 2], 2]
```

> ```
> Mod[2 + n, 2]
> ```

This happens because `IntegerDigits` stays unevaluated for non integer inputs:

```
IntegerDigits[n, 2]
```

> ```
> IntegerDigits[n, 2]
> ```

Note that this sum remains unevaluated:

```
Sum[ThueMorse[n]/(n + 1)^s, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> Sum[ThueMorse[n]/(n + 1)^s, {n, 0, Infinity}]
> ```

Ideally Alpha should be using the System symbol rather than its own macro. The results [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ThueMorse%5Bn%5D) are just wrong for the reasons mentioned above. I'll file feedback to make sure this gets fixed.

Comment: Great, thank you!